# Tablerate Shipping not working in magento 1.6.2 when coupon code applied

Tags: magento

**Store Info:**

A very simple store with two store views(Danish/english) 12 products(2 configurable and all are simple) and one category.

**What I did:**

Enabled Table rate shipping method to give different shipping prices based on country and product weight. It did working exactly as What it is supposed to work.

Then created coupon code to for people who are buying from particular Attribute Set and coupon code also worked with that condition.

**Problem:**

But when i apply coupon code then the shipping method tab gives "Sorry no quote available message". And when i remove the coupon code then again the shipping tab works fine.

While creating coupon code i created it with "Stop Further Rules Processing" = Yes since I remember it was problem on other store sometime back.  But anyway its not giving the table rate shipping method here.

[image]

Solution needed for this. Please can anyone guess what could be the issue?